# how to replicate plot: density bar plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm working on a project and would like to plot by data in a similar way as this example from a book:
[image]

So I would like to create a density histogram for my categorical features (left image) and than add a separate column for each value of another feature (middle and right image).

In my case the feature I want to plot is called [district_code] and I would like to create columns based on a feature called [status_group]

What I've tried so far:

- `sns.kdeplot(data = raw, x = "district_code")`: problem, it is a line plot, not a histogram
- `sns.kdeplot(data = raw, x = "district_code", col = "status_group")`: problem, you can't use the col argument for this plottype
- `sns.displot(raw, x="district_code", col = 'status_group')`: problem, col argument works, but it creates a countplot, not a density plot

I would really appreciate some suggestions about the correct code I could use.

This is just an example for one of my categorical features, but I have many more I would like to plot. Any suggestions on how to turn this into a function where I could run the code for a list of categorical features would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE:

- sns.displot(raw, x="source_class", stat = 'density', col = 'status_group', color = 'black'): works but looks a bit akward for some features.

How could I improve this?

Good:
[image]

Not so good:
[image]

Comment: Did you try `sns.displot(...., stat='density')`?  The `displot` docs explain *Other keyword arguments are documented with the relevant axes-level function, e.g.`histplot()` (with kind="hist")*

Comment: Hi, that actually improved things a bit, but some of my features look a bit akward (see updates picture). How could I improve this?

Comment: It is unclear how your data look like.  Maybe the last example is numeric, but discrete? So, you could call `sns.displot(...., discrete=True)`? Or maybe set explicit bins (e.g. `bins=np.arange(0, 81, 5)`)?

Comment: I turned this feature to a object type, so It shouldnt be numerical. The discrete = True parameter does work